# Error while accessing contents from other website using php and curl

Tags: php, curl, certificate

error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /var/local/etc/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none

I am getting the above error while accessing the content of a website using php with curl. I am very new to using both php and curl so not able to find the solution. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

running these commands should fix the problem:

```
sudo rm -rfv /var/local/etc/ca-bundle.crt
sudo curl -o /var/local/etc/ca-bundle.crt https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
sudo chmod 0444 /var/local/etc/ca-bundle.crt
```

some pages you can check for details: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority

Comment: I can see this in terminalPoojas-MacBook-Pro:~ poojadeole$ sudo curl -o /var/local/etc/ca-bundle.crt https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file /var/local/etc/ca-bundle.crt: No such file 
Warning: or directory
  0  230k    0  2068    0     0  10578      0  0:00:22 --:--:--  0:00:22 10605
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 2068)

Comment: Sorry...but I can't exactly understand where is /var/local/etc/ca-bundle.crt

Comment: huh. add --create-dirs  to the curl command then. `sudo curl -o /var/local/etc/ca-bundle.crt --create-dirs https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem`